# "beta", "public beta", but not "private beta" in the area51 listing?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, area-51

[image]

Shouldn't *Electronics and Robotics* say "private beta"?

Not only "public beta" is misleading information, but stating whether the beta is private or public helps the 80% of our users who don't know or remember how long the private beta lasts.

Comment: By the way, those ugly things in the SS are supposed to be question marks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electronics & Robotics skipped private beta because it was an SE 1.0 conversion of chiphacker.com.  So the behavior here is correct.

We do say "private beta" if the site is in private beta.

Comment: All right then; I assumed it was private beta because of the days. Thanks!